# Xcode: Cannot change target membership for folders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a number of folders in my Resources group. I want to include some of them in target A and some in target B. To this end I created two subfolders:

```
Resources
 - content
 -- A
 -- B
```

If I try to change target membership for 'content' I can, under 'Get Info', select the targets. If I try the same for 'A' and 'B', under the 'Targets' tab, there are no targets listed.

Anyone have a hunch what the problem might be? Not possible with subfolders?

Comment: Are the folders shown in yellow or blue?

Comment: They are blue, folders not groups...

Comment: What happens if you drag them to the target under 'Copy Resources?'

Comment: I am now using two folders on the "root" level. That solves the problem. I guess you can only set membership recursively. Which makes a lot of sense now that I think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because you set the target membership recursively, so a subfolder inherits from its parent.